# How can I get the most relevant document ID for each bucket in the facet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudsearch

How can I get the most relevant document ID for each bucket in the facet.
For example, i would like to know the most relevant document ID for buckets  "Comedy", "Drama", "Adventure" and other:

```
<results>
    <status rid="v7r9hs8oFQqMHnk=" time-ms="3"/>
    <hits found="85" start="0">
        <hit id="tt1411664"/>
        <hit id="tt1911658"/>
        <hit id="tt0086190"/>
        <hit id="tt0120601"/>
        <hit id="tt2141761"/>
        <hit id="tt1674771"/>
        <hit id="tt0056687"/>
        <hit id="tt0397892"/>
        <hit id="tt0258153"/>
        <hit id="tt0796366"/>
    </hits>
    <facets>
        <facet name="genres">
            <bucket value="Comedy" count="41"/>  <<???? What is the most relevant document ID for this bucket? 
            <bucket value="Drama" count="35"/> <<???? What is the most relevant document ID for this bucket?
            <bucket value="Adventure" count="29"/>  <<???? What is the most relevant document ID for this bucket?
            <bucket value="Sci-Fi" count="24"/> <<???? What is the most relevant document ID for this bucket?
            <bucket value="Action" count="20"/> <<???? What is the most relevant document ID for this bucket?
        </facet>
    </facets>
</results>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make one query per facet. Specify the facet in a filter query, for example:

`fq=genres:'Comedy'&size=1`

Have a look at the docs for using facet information:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/faceting.html

Comment: Yes it is correct  but to get results for few bucket i have to do 5 requests and i would like to get result by one request for 5 buckets